# Object (Optional Any): get elements

Tags: ios, swift, object, notifications

I'm trying to pass information with an observed notification in my app.
The standard way to do that, is to set the userinfo. However, the data I want to pass is a Set, not a dictionary.

So, I do this:

`NotificationCenter.default.post(name: MY_NOTIFICATION_NAME, object:self.productIds)`

The object arrives fine, but now I'm unable to get to it:

in the console I do this:

```
po notification.object!
▿ 2 elements
 - 0 : ZTJ
 - 1 : ZTM
```

However, when I try to get to one of the elements, I get this:

```
po notification.object![0]
error: <EXPR>:8:21: error: value of type 'Any' has no subscripts
notification.object![0]
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is the type of `self.productIds`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You know that `notification.object` is a `Set`, but the compiler doesn't because it's declared as `Any`, which means it could be anything, and so it can't find which implementation of `object[0]` it should use.

To read this object you need to cast it to a set.

```
if let mySet = notification.object as? Set<MyType> {
  // Do whatever
}
```

Keep in mind that the `object` property of `Notification` is designed to be used as a filter, If you pass a value when adding an observer, you'll only get notifications that are sent with that exact same object.

The `userInfo` dictionary is to send related information, like your set. In this case I would send a dictionary like this:

```
NotificationCenter.default.post(name: MY_NOTIFICATION_NAME, object: nil, userInfo: ["products": productIds])
```

Comment: That's an excellent point about object vs userInfo, I was so distracted by the type that I forgot to mention that. Have a +1 :)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I got more than I asked for!

Answer (score 1):

The notification has an object type of `Any?`.

When you're `po`ing it in the console, you're asking it to print its description, which `Any` can do.

When you're asking it to subscript, `Any` can't do that, because subscripting is not defined on that type. You need to cast it to the expected type:

```
po (notification.object as? [String])?[0]
```

In general, it's best to nail down the type of any `Any` as soon as you can. Think of `Any` as a box used to send things through the post. The first thing you do is open it and find out what's inside.

Comment: “Box in the Post” is excellent.